# Laravel replicate works but not inserting into database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, replicate

I am trying to replicates a record in my database here is my controller

```
private Receiver $receiver;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->receiver = new Receiver();
    ...
}

$this->receiver = $receiverData;
        if ($reversed) {
            $receiver = Receiver::find($receiverData['id']);
            $new_receiver = $receiver->replicate();
            $this->receiver = $new_receiver;
        } else {
            $this->receiver->user_id = $receiverData->user_id = auth()->id();
        }

        $this->receiver->save();
        dd($this->receiver);
```

Now the debug shows correct results

```
#attributes: array:11 [▶
    "user_id" => 1
    "city_id" => 2
    "name" => "Mohamed"
    "address" => "Al noor st. 15 city"
    "phone" => "054545488877"
    "email" => "Yousef@alatraf.com.sa"
    "latitude" => null
    "longitude" => null
    "updated_at" => "2023-11-26 18:09:38"
    "created_at" => "2023-11-26 18:09:38"
    "id" => 148
  ]
```

But it dose not insert any records to my database any idea what could be the issue here.

Comment: how do we know that is the correct result? how do we know that isn't an already existing record?

Comment: I think we need some additional info on this one. You're first initializing `$this->receiver` with a new `Receiver` model, only to overwrite it with`$receiverData`. Where does $receiverData come from? How is `$reversed` determined?

Comment: try excluding the id field if you want to save the replica as a new model.

Comment: Sorry My code was not clear I have made some modifications.

Comment: I am using MySQL 8 and the issue was I am trying to replicate the record without changing anything so MySQL was updating the record instead of inserting new one Found this in MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)